# Why we study vector bundles?

Tags: math-history, vector-bundles, applications

For my lecture on vector bundles I would like to show to students why it is important to study vector bundles. It is a very abstract structure in mathematics, but I want to show the applications in life. Does anybody know these applications of vector bundles? Thanks!

Comment: Vector bundles can help you win the lottery! Or not. I don't see how there could be a real life application except in physics.

Comment: @MattSamuel for instance, in physics. What example?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauge_theory